# rails controller action AND javascript onclick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button-to

I am trying to do both: call a controller action and react to onclick with a javascript function. At the moment, I only can do one thing. Trying with

```
<%= button_to 'Call Action', contoller_action_path, :remote => true,
              :method => 'post',
              :onclick => "setSomeJsState('Run'); return(false);" %>
```

it triggers only the `onclick` part.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
devyn

Comment: why not just call a controller action in the `setSomeJsState()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return false` in js event disables event propagation, and thus rails ujs code to handle button does not run.

Other option is to make an `$.ajax` call to the action in `setSomeJsState` function.